# No cells were found

Tags: vba

I am using below to highlight empty cells but when there is no empty cells, it's giving debug `no cells were found`. I tried to disable debug or resume on error but nothing is working.

```
    Sub test2()
    Dim dataset As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataset = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastrow, 30))
    dataset.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check that there are blanks before.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim dataset As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set dataset = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 30))

        If Application.CountIf(Intersect(.UsedRange, dataset), "") > 0 Then
            dataset.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `On Error Resume Next` along with `On Error GoTo 0` when specifying your special range. Afterwards, check if the range is empty before continuing.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim dataset As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
        Set dataset = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastrow, 30)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not dataset Is Nothing Then dataset.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```